# 'Contributors' delete selfmade posts without having access to backend

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, backend

Long story short, I have a wordpress site build from scratch, people can use the front-end to sign up as 'contributors', go to a specific page, and create custom post types, all from the front-end.

Now I managed to give them the possibility to 'edit' the post, or 'delete' it, however!

I also don't want them in the backend, ever. So I added this script to my functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
    function blockusers_init() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Commenting this out, and everything works, but with it, they sure can't acces the backend with a /wp-admin URL, but they can't delete their posts either, I'm assuming this somehow blocks that requests, any clues as what I could do?

Comment: I'd try using Justin Tadlock's [members plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) to create a new role with just the permissions you need, set that as the default role for new signups, and transfer the existing users into that role.

Comment: Ditto. Justin Tadlock's members plugin is a great way to go. Using "current_user_can( 'role' )" is not a recommended way to control permissions. The function "current_user_can" was created to be used  with capabilities, not with roles.